# CiviVolunteer:running on Joomla screen blank, only see header "CiviVolunteer"

Tags: joomla, civivolunteer

I have a civi 5.8.2 install running on Joomla 3.9.1 (unilingual), I have installed CiviVolunteer and I am trying to enable the volunteer Opportunity Listing.
I have installed:
Angular Profiles (org.civicrm.angularprofiles) version 4.7.31-1.1.2
CiviVolunteer (org.civicrm.volunteer) version 4.7.31-2.3.1
The link I used is:
http://address-to-your-site/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities
I view a page titled "CiviVolunteer". I see below the title my CiviCRM system status (I am logged in as superuser into the front end).
Has anyone got it working? I would love to have the interface as seen for drupal users, the sample site looks awesome.

Here's the info from Dev Tools, "Console":
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js:2:542

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:161:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:163:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/lodash-compat/lodash.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:165:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:167:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:169:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.form.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:171:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.timeentry.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:173:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.blockUI.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:175:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:177:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:179:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:181:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:183:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.datepicker.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:185:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:187:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.wysiwyg.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:189:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.tableHeader.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:191:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.menu.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:193:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.optionEdit.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:195:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.joomla.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:197:1

TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined[Learn More] index.php:8:3

TypeError: CRM.wysiwyg is undefined[Learn More] crm.tinymce.js:21:3

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.notify.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:205:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:207:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.angular.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:209:1

ReferenceError: angular is not defined[Learn More] angular-modules.1382ac9fdf35e52380a62a87a198cccb.js:23:1

Loading failed for the  with source “https://address-to-your-site/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/noconflict.js?r=0tqbB”. index.php:213:1

Comment: It sounds like you have a JavaScript error.  If you press F12 you'll bring up your browser's "dev tools".  Look at the "Console" tab and edit your question to include any errors you see there?  Thanks!

Comment: If you go to Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs, what is 'CiviCRM Resource URL' set to?

Comment: Hi Andrew, here it is: [civicrm.root]/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing 'CiviCRM Resource URL' from `[civicrm.root]` to `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/`. Your console is showing that the URLs are missing `administrator` so I think you are affected by this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/5